# $(k,n)$-binary graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $k\leq n$ be positive integers with $n\geq 2$, and let $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Let $V_n=\{0,1\}^{[n]}$ be the set of all functions $f:[n]\to\{0,1\}$, and let 
$$E_{k,n} =\big\{\{f,g\}: f,g\in V_n\text{ and } |\{m\in [n]:f(m)\neq g(m)\}|=k\big\}.$$
We call $G_{k,n} = (V_n,E_{k,n})$ the $(k,n)$-*binary graph*. It is easy to see that if $k,n$ have common divisors, then $G_{k,n}$ is not connected (there is no path from the constant $0$-function to the function $g:[n]\to\{0,1\}$ where $g(1)=1$ and $g(m) = 0$ for $m\in[n]\setminus \{1\}$).

**Question.** If $k, n$ are relatively prime, is $G_{k,n}$ connected? If yes, what is the length of the longest path?

(Will accept the first correct answer that addresses the first question, but will also upvote useful answers on the second question.)

Comment: I suspect this is a Gray code in disguise, and that you can get an answer which is one or two less than N, the number of all vertices for longest path, or at least N -  O(log N). Gerhard "Should Try Some Small Examples" Paseman, 2018.10.02.

Comment: Also, for the (3,6) graph, I see a path, contrary to your claim. I suspect the graph is disconnected iff k is even (by an easy coloring argument), and that it has at most two connected components.  Gerhard "Taking A Big Leap Here" Paseman, 2018.10.02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the coprimality of $k$ and $n$ does not imply that $G_{k,n}$ is connected. For a counterexample we consider the case $(k,n)=(2,3)$.

Represent a function $f\in V_3$ by the sequence $(f(1),f(2),f(3))$. Then $V_{2,3}$ is the disjoint union of two complete graphs with $4$ vertices each. The first one has vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(1,1,0)$, $(1,0,1)$, and $(0,1,1)$; the second one has vertices $(1,1,1)$, $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$.

More generally, if $k$ is even, then the parity of the sum of the entries remains invariant when passing along an edge. Hence $G_{k,n}$ is not connected.

Comment: Can you confirm my conjecture above about even k? Gerhard "Almost Sure It Is Obvious" Paseman, 2018.10.02.

Comment: Never mind. Let F be the subset with an even number of zeros and G a component with an odd number of zeros. F and G are connected components, and F is connected to G iff k is odd. I think the longest path can be found by an appropriate traversal of F and G.  Gerhard "Coffee Not Working Fast Today" Paseman, 2018.10.02.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Sorry, when writing the answer I had not really noticed your second comment that an easy parity argument works for all even $k$. So I have made the answer CW and added the remark about even $k$.

Comment: No biggie.  You might observe that F and G have Hamiltonian cycles (sort of) which I think lead to a quick proof of longest path, or at least a good lower bound.  Gerhard "Prefers Easy Arguments This Morning" Paseman, 2018.10.02.